# How can I view the responses of contact forms on different sites in one panel or elsewhere?

Tags: plugins

how can i show responses for forms on my multiple sites in a single database or a single panel or elsewhere?
The reason I want this is that it is difficult to look at 4 different sites every day, since the answers from the form appear in the wordpress admin panel, it is difficult to enter the admin panel every day and check it.
In short, the aim is to show the answers of the forms from different sites in one place.

Comment: WordPress has no built in contact form functionality, you would need to find a solution for the specific unique contact form plugin that you chose to use. It isn't possible to write an answer that works for all contact form plugins, and questions about specific 3rd party plugins/products/services are offtopic here

Comment: also stop re-asking the same question worded slightly differently, I've closed the other duplicates as duplicates, this site is not an appropriate to ask this question. _Go to the support routes of the forum/contact form plugin you used, or a group/community of people who use it._ If you keep trying to ask it here you'll get blocked from asking questions automatically by the sites anti-bot/moderation code